# Magento getting product description by loadByAttribute

Tags: magento

I am trying to get product details using below code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', 'skuValue');
```

I am getting all the other details except product description.

Can anyone please tell  me how can i get the product description with above method.

Thank You Very Much.

Answer (score 1):

Try var_dump($product->getData()) this should give you all the attributes available. If you don't have access to description, then you will have to use addAttributeToSelect.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $product->getShortDescription(); //product's short description
echo $product->getDescription(); //product's description
```

This will give you the description and short description.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply. I tried this way. Only the short description is getting. But not description.